# Is it possible to investigate if a pendrive has been connected to a specific PC?

Tags: usb-drive

Is it possible to investigate if a pendrive has been connected to a specific PC? Are there any traces left on the device?

Comment: depends on the device if it logs anything - for as cheap as they are, no

Comment: Wait, do you mean that you have the PC and want to check if a certain device connected to it?

Comment: A registry key is usually created which contains either the serial number or another identifier for the USB device. You can find it under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try USBDeview utility.
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html
Traces might be left on the PC, but not the device.

Comment: The device keeps no information of the latest PC it was connected to?

Comment: I suppose that could depend on the driver of the device but I've never seen that on any device.